# Which program was used to create this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3ds-max, blender

How was this created?

[image]

Using a 3d program like blender, 3DS max or Photoshop?

Comment: I dont think this image is made in a 3D application. Photoshop is not a 3D application

Comment: Impossible to know.

Comment: There's no helpful metadata in the PNG file.

Comment: You would have to ask the artist. I doubt it is straight out of a 3D app, but It could have started as a 3D render and was then finished in PS or it may be all done in PS.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in any painting program. Photoshop, Gimp, PhotoPaint, Krita, Painter, Paint.net, Paint, etc.